# Screen orientation issues on iPad Air

Tags: objective-c, ios8, xcode6

I have disabled all orientations except Portrait that is **UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait** app works fine on iPhones but on iPad Air screen rotates I don't know why. I have tried many solution but none of them worked for me. Any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the targets sections please confirm the following settings are used.
[image: inside Project -> Targets -> General]

Comment: its already checked. Its universal app and just portrait option is checked

Comment: Then It might be some other issue.